# How to get multiple columns of values from OPENJSON and cross apply

Tags: json, sql-server, database, open-json

I am using SQL Server inside Visual Studio 2019. I have downloaded a large JSON file [for US Zip codes](https://public.opendatasoft.com/explore/dataset/us-zip-code-latitude-and-longitude/export/?q=). My goal is to get all the properties from the fields, which look like this:

[image]

and save their properties in my database.

I don't care about performance, as I just want to do this once, so I can access them forever. So far I can get this:

[image]

But it just comes in as one long column. I tried doing some select statements like this:

```
SELECT
JSON_VALUE(v.[value],'$.fields.city')   AS City
```

but it comes with a JSON formatted text incorrectly.
How can I get the JSON file into my DB?

Comment: if you could post your sample in text values that would be easier

Comment: @Avi what in text values? I posted a screenshot of the JSON values, is that not what you mean?

Comment: if the sample data is in text format..people can just copy past and try their solution else they have to spend time creating the sample data as well

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it. The final SQL to parse the JSON and add it into a table looks like this:

```
DECLARE @ZIP VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @ZIP = BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'D:\Downloads\us-zip-code-latitude-and-longitude.json', SINGLE_CLOB) AS j
SELECT * 
INTO ZipData
FROM OPENJSON(@ZIP)
WITH (
    City VARCHAR(255) '$.fields.city',
    Zip INT '$.fields.zip',
    DST INT '$.fields.dst',
    Longitude FLOAT '$.fields.longitude',
    State VARCHAR(255) '$.fields.state',
    Latitude FLOAT '$.fields.latitude',
    TimeZone INT '$.fields.timezone'
)
```